# how to create test class with Rest Callouts using PageReference.getParameters().put method

Tags: apex, httpcalloutmock

I am using this method to fetch data :
final PageReference link = new PageReference( 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/tooling/query');
 link.getParameters().put('q','select id from Account');
 HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
 request.setEndpoint(link.getUrl());

I have checked with many links regarding callouts ,  salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/httpcalloutmock-interface-where-there-is-more-than-1-callout  and [Writing a test class for multi-callout method using MockHttpResponseGenerator](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33263/writing-a-test-class-for-multi-callout-method-using-mockhttpresponsegenerator)  , but none have used this method. Can Anybody help me regarding this ?

Comment: Your questions is not clear. You would get better support if you [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/167109/edit) your question, add the problem and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have edited the question.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @RahulSharma.... this is my code. And I want implement test class for this :   final PageReference link = new PageReference( 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/tooling/query'); link.getParameters().put('q','select id from Account'); HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); request.setEndpoint(link.getUrl());

Comment: where can we see your test class?

Comment: @Rahul ...I dont have much idea about it.., how to start this kind of issue?